# Moving average and difference

Tags: awk

I would like to calculate moving/rolling average on column 2 ($2) in my data file (data.txt) using a window of 5 (over five consecutive rows) and then the difference between the first and the last value within each window using AWK. Please see my data below:

```
> cat data.txt
2001         100
2002         110
2003         120
2004         130
2005         140
2006         900
2007         910
2008         920
2009         930
2010         940

> awk 'BEGIN{size=5} {mod=NR%size; if(NR<=size){count++}else{sum-=array[mod]};sum+=$2;array[mod]=$2;print $1"\t", $2"\t", sum/count}' data.txt
2001     100     100
2002     110     105
2003     120     110
2004     130     115
2005     140     120
2006     900     280
2007     910     440
2008     920     600
2009     930     760
2010     940     920
```

As can be seen in the accompanying output above, I can do the moving average on $2 (output is in $3) using the AWK script shown above. But, how can I modify my AWK script above so that I can also print out the difference in $4 between the first and last value of $2 for each window? For example, I would like the above output to look like this:

```
2001     100     100     
2002     110     105
2003     120     110
2004     130     115
2005     140     120      120-100
2006     900     280      280-105
2007     910     440      440-110
2008     920     600      600-115
2009     930     760      760-120
2010     940     920      920-280
```

Comment: "print out the difference in $4 between the first and last value of $2 for each window" -- then shouldn't you have "140-100", "900-110", etc? Did you mean "print out the difference in $4 between the *moving average* and *first* value of $2 for each window"?

Answer (score 1):

Before you replace `array[mod]`, save the difference another variable so you can print it in the new column.

```
awk 'BEGIN{size=5} 
    {   mod=NR%size; 
        if(NR<=size){count++;}
        else{sum-=array[mod]};
        sum+=$2;
        if (NR >= size) {diff = $2"-"array[mod]}
        array[mod]=$2;
        print $1"\t", $2"\t", sum/count"\t", diff
    }' data.txt
```

Comment: Thank you, Barmar! You are genius. This did the trick. I am super happy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to also remember the last values of the third column:

```
awk 'BEGIN{size=5}
{
  mod=NR%size; 
  if(NR<=size) {
    count++
  } else {
    sum-=array[mod]
  };
  sum+=$2;
  avg=sum/count;
  if (NR>=size) {
    diff=avg"-"array2[(mod+1)%size]; # remove quotes to display result as a number
  }
  array[mod]=$2;
  array2[mod]=avg;

  print $1"\t", $2"\t", avg, diff
}
' data.txt
```

EDIT: your current description does not match the example in the question ($4 should be a difference from $2 or $3?). My answer solves your example and Barmars your description :)

Comment: Thank you, Gyuri16! This is exactly what I was looking for. You came to my rescue.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not tied to awk, perl is pretty tidy. This assumes you mean, for column 4, the difference between the first and last *average* of the window.

```
perl -MList::Util=sum0 -slane '
    unshift @values, $F[1];            # add current value to window of values
    splice @values, $size;             # trim window to desired size
    $avg = sum0(@values) / scalar(@values);

    unshift @averages, $avg;
    splice @averages, $size;

    push @F, $avg;
    # remove quotes below if you want the actual difference
    push @F, "$averages[0]-$averages[-1]" if scalar(@values) == $size;
    print join "\t", @F
' -- -size=5 data.txt
```

```
2001    100     100
2002    110     105
2003    120     110
2004    130     115
2005    140     120     120-100
2006    900     280     280-105
2007    910     440     440-110
2008    920     600     600-115
2009    930     760     760-120
2010    940     920     920-280
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn! I am not so familiar with Perl. Awk took care of this for me.